# java coin toss simulator problems

Tags: java, computer-science

hi i am doing a coin toss simulator for java that must be done a certain way. it must have a string for sideup to hold the string of "heads" or "tails" made by a no arg constructor, the toss method must be void and it must have a getsideup method, then we must run the coin toss 20 times and diplay the number of heads and tails... i can do it easy with none void methods and just returning the result, but getting around this void and getsideup is driving me nuts.
this is what i have so far.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class coin {
    public static String sideUp;

    public static void toss() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int sideup = rand.nextInt(2);
        if (sideup == 0) {
            sideUp = "heads";
        } else {
            sideUp = "tails";
        }
    }

    public static String getsideup() {
        System.out.println(sideUp);
        return sideUp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // coin coin = new coin();
        int hcount = 0;
        int tcount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (getsideup().equals("heads")) {
                hcount++;
            } else {
                tcount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("total heads = " + hcount + " total tails = " + tcount);
    }
}
```

im hoping someone can tell me what im doing wrong and put me in the right direction.

Comment: Shouldn't you call ```toss()``` in that for cycle? Other than that I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling toss() at the beginning of your loop. That's required to set a value to sideUp, and required to give sideUp to change every toss.

Comment: calling the toss() in the for loop worked its now running i believe the way the book is asking, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is put toss in your for loop before the if statement but I see a lot that can be done here. First I would add a constructor for the Coin class and add hcount and tcount to the class variables and make heads and tails constants:

```
private String sideUp;
private int hcount;
private int tcount;
private static final String HEADS = "Heads";
private static final String Tails = "Tails";

Coin()
{
    this.sideUp = HEADS;
    this.hcount = 0;
    this.tcount = 0;
}
```

Then I would make a method to check the toss:

```
public  void checkToss()
{
    if (getsideup().equals(HEADS)) 
        hcount++;
    else
        tcount++;
}
```

Now add the toss() and checkCoin() method to the for loop before the if statement. It should look like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    coin.toss(); 
    coin.checkToss();
}
```

I would also make a getter for the heads count and tails count:

```
public int getHeadsCount()
{
    return this.hcount;
}

public int getTailsCount()
{
    return this.tcount;
}
```

Everything put together looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Coin 
{
    private  String sideUp;
    private int hcount;
    private int tcount;
    private static final String HEADS = "Heads";
    private static final String TAILS = "Tails";

    Coin()
    {
        this.sideUp = HEADS;
        this.hcount = 0;
        this.tcount = 0;
    }

    public void toss()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int sideup = rand.nextInt(2);
        if (sideup == 0) 
            sideUp = HEADS;
        else 
            sideUp = TAILS;    
    }

    public String getsideup()
    {
        System.out.println(sideUp);
        return sideUp;
    }

    public void checkToss()
    {
    if (getsideup().equals(HEADS)) 
        this.hcount++;
    else
        this.tcount++;
    }

    public int getHeadsCount()
    {
        return this.hcount;
    }

    public int getTailsCount()
    {
        return this.tcount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Coin coin = new Coin();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) 
        {
            coin.toss();
            coin.checkToss();
        }
        System.out.println("Total Heads = " + coin.getHeadsCount() + " Total Tails = " + coin.getTailsCount());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) 
    {
        toss();
      if (getsideup().equals("heads")) 
      {
        hcount++;
      } else 
      {
        tcount++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's mixing responsibilities. I think it is confusing to add toss to the getter.

Comment: Then call the toss() method from the for loop man! I have edited my post... I was just trying to help you... no point down voting!

Comment: Also no point in getting upset when someone points out that they think your answer isn't very good. It's going to happen often when you answer questions here, regardless of how good you are. Just try to learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Random;
public class coin
{
public static String sideUp;
public int hcount=0;
public int tcount=0;

public static void toss()
     {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int sideup = rand.nextInt(2);
        if (sideup == 0)
            {
                sideUp = "heads";
                hcount++;
            }
            else 
            {
                sideUp  = "tails";
                tcount++;
            } 
      }       

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {toss();}
    System.out.println("total heads = " + hcount + " total tails = " + tcount);
   }
}
```

Comment: Makes it much easier if you increment the count in the toss method, rather than trying to set a String, call that in another method and increment it there.

Comment: Well then you will have to have a setter as well, then setSide() in the toss method. Otherwise your not setting a value for the getter to retrieve.